# Recreate same array from new one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array from which I take some values to create some fields of a form. After creating it I need to send the new array that I fill automatically to the server. The problem is that I need to send the same array from the first but of course with the new values. I created here the example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/2/

Some code here:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='mycontroller'>

    <div data-ng-repeat="item in myNewArray.newArray track by $index">
        <div ng-if="item.attrType == 'text'">
            <input id="form-f{{$index}}" type="text" placeholder="{{item.attrname}}" data-ng-model="item.attrValue"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="object in getItems.data">
        <div data-ng-repeat="att in object.objects">
            <ul ng-repeat="data in att.attributes">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="pushItems(att.name, data)">{{data.attrname}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>


    <p>{{showNewJson()}}</p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "$http",
    function($scope, $http){
        $scope.getItems = {
    "data": [
        {
            "label": "first",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd1",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd2",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "key": "bolla"
        },
        {
            "label": "second",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "secondObj",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd3",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "key": "2"
        }
    ]

};
    $scope.filterSelected = $scope.getItems.data[0].objects;

        $scope.myNewArray = {
            newArray: [

            ]
        }
        $scope.pushItems = function pushItems(attribute, items) {
            $scope.myNewArray.newArray.push(angular.copy(attribute), angular.copy(items));
            console.log($scope.myNewArray);
        }

        $scope.showNewJson = function() {
            return $scope.myNewArray;
        }
}]);
```

ps: I'm using angularjs

EDIT: i updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/3/

This should be the correct json i would:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "name": "firstObj",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "attrname": "asd1",
                    "attrValue": "asdas",
                    "attrType": "text"
                },
                {
                    "attrname": "asd2",
                    "attrValue": "sadsa",
                    "attrType": "text"
                },
                {
                    "name": "secondObj",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd3",
                            "attrValue": "tttt",
                            "attrType": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd4",
                            "attrValue": "qqq",
                            "attrType": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am not really sure where the issue is. You click on the li's and it adds a new input and it adds to your new array. whats the issue?

Comment: The new json (the one that is showed in <p> tag : "<p>{{showNewJson()}}</p>" has to be the same of: "$scope.getItems" what i need it's find a way to group the new attributes by objects like the first one. Understand now?

Comment: Nope. Can you post an example of what you expect. Sorry I couldn't understand

Comment: Ok just wait a minute that i try to edit my quest

Comment: Do you want the structure of your newJson to be same as $scope.getItems?

Comment: Check the edit. You should understand now. Maybe use http://pro.jsonlint.com/ to compare the json better

Comment: Checking it! will let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76636/discussion-between-pratik-and-end-game).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my final answer - https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/8/

```
$scope.myNewArray = {
            objects: [

            ]
        }

        $scope.createjson = function(attribute, items) {
            var obj = {};
            obj.name = angular.copy(attribute);
            obj.attributes = [];
            obj.attributes.push(angular.copy(items));
            return obj;
        }

        $scope.checkIfAttributeExists = function(attribute) {        
            for(var i=0; i<$scope.myNewArray.objects.length; i++) {                
                if($scope.myNewArray.objects[i]["name"] == attribute) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        $scope.pushItems = function pushItems(attribute, items) {
            var index = $scope.checkIfAttributeExists(attribute);
            if(index == -1) {
                var obj = $scope.createjson(attribute, items);
                $scope.myNewArray.objects.push(obj);
            }
            else {
                $scope.myNewArray.objects[index].attributes.push(items);
            }


            //console.log($scope.myNewArray);
        }

        $scope.showNewJson = function() {
            return $scope.myNewArray;
        }
```

Comment: I'm outside right now, let me about 10 minutes and I'll try :-)

Comment: Ok, i'm here. The json seems correctly formatted..just only one more question; right now the creation of the input doesn't work anymore with your code. Could you please take a look why?

Comment: Sorry was busy! Glad that it helped!

Comment: no problem, i will create another one question in about 10 minutes because i need something else. Can you help me again?

Comment: :D sure. Can you just post a link to that question here?

Comment: Yes of course. But if you want we can open a chat right now ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76650/discussion-between-end-game-and-pratik).